# How can I find the modulation schemes used for the packet transmission using wireshark?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark

I am using wireshark to find the modulation schemes and the type of packets captured for [802.11ac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ac).

How can I find the modulation schemes used for the packet transmission?
Preferably using wireshark?
Should I use other tool to capture 802.11ac packets?

Answer (score 1):

The modulation scheme is meta-data about the packet that the radio knows, but it's not part of the bits of the packet itself.

Some 802.11 cards and drivers have a way to record and pass along to the sniffer this radio meta data with each frame. Radiotap and PPI are two frame capture formats that include the radio meta-data. If your card an driver support them, you can select them in the data link type pop-up menu of Witeshark's Capture Options window.

On Mac OS X 10.7 "Lion" and later, these are supported by default on the Mac's built-in Wi-Fi card. One or the other is probably supported on most Linux drivers. On Windows, you might have to buy an AirPcap capture dongle to get that option.

Comment: You will also need to capture in monitor mode to get the meta-data.  Wireshark's monitor mode check box should work on OS X; it probably currently won't work on most Linux systems, but the [airmon-ng script](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng) in aircrack-ng (which is probably available as a deb/RPM/etc. package for most Linux distributions) should let you turn monitor mode on.